# Redis pipelining is not working after removing sleep

Tags: redis

I am reading about redis pipelining, where I saw the basic example.

The below command is working as expected.

```
(printf "PING\r\nPING\r\nPING\r\n"; sleep 1) | nc localhost 6379
```

Output:

```
+PONG
+PONG
+PONG
```

But when I remove sleep, then the command is not giving me any result.

```
(printf "PING\r\nPING\r\nPING\r\n";) | nc localhost 6379
```

I am not able to understand the behavior here. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the commands before the pipe (`|`), e.g. `(printf "PING\r\nPING\r\nPING\r\n";)`, finishes, it sends an **EOF** to the `nc` command, and `nc` will close the connection to Redis, and exit. However, before `nc` exits, it might haven't received the response from Redis.

In order to ensure that `nc` receives the response from Redis and outputs it, after `printf` the request, it sleeps a while, e.g. `sleep 1`. Normally, `nc` can receive the response from Redis in `1` second. So that you can see the output.